# Bootstrap modal to appear on successful form submit

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I've currently got a modal setup which I would like to open only when the required fields are filled then the submit button is hit. Currently it only seems to appear when there are required fields remaining.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" runat="server">
    <div class="container">
        <br />
        <legend>32 User Search</legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:Label ID="lb32Number" runat="server" Text="32 Number:" CssClass="col-md-4 control-label"></asp:Label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <asp:TextBox ID="tb32Number" runat="server" CssClass="form-control input-md" required=""></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <asp:Button ID="btSearch" runat="server" text="Search" CssClass="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".user" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal fade user" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <asp:Label ID="tbName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Also note I am using bootstrap in conjunction with ASP.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Can't you do that with jQuery?

Comment: @D4V1D I'm trying to avoid that, I thought this would be something simple that wouldn't require any extra jQuery.

Comment: If you want the condition the opening of the modal based on the value of several `input` fields, you **should** use jQuery